# how to check if the object is python list using isintance function

Tags: python

```
import json
import requests
r=requests.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AliasIO/Wappalyzer/master/src/apps.json')
wappalyzer=r.json()

def enumarate_keys(parent_key,json_obj):
    x=0
    enumarated_keys={}
    for key in json_obj[parent_key]:
        enumarated_keys[x]=key
        x=x+1
    return enumarated_keys
# enumerate tech
list_of_apps=enumarate_keys('apps',wappalyzer)
# enumerate properties of a tech
properties=enumarate_keys(list_of_apps[0],wappalyzer['apps'])
data=json.dumps(wappalyzer['apps'][list_of_apps[0]]['script']) #[u'checkout\\.google\\.com', u'wallet\\.google\\.com']
print '1st check i got false:\n'
print data #> ["checkout\\.google\\.com", "wallet\\.google\\.com"]
print isinstance(data, list) 
print '\n\n'
print 'second check i got true:\n'
data1=["checkout\\.google\\.com", "wallet\\.google\\.com"]
print isinstance(data1, list) 

print('\ncheck if data and data1 are equal:')
if data == data1:
    print 'equal'
else:
    print 'not equal'
```

In line 17, the json_dumps() function is called to transform `[u'checkout\\.google\\.com', u'wallet\\.google\\.com']` into `["checkout\\.google\\.com", "wallet\\.google\\.com"]`
then in line 20 the `isinstance` function checks for a list. if the object is a list, it will return true otherwise false, but it returns false—it should be true,isn't?.

In line 23, the data1 variable contains an indentical value of data variable and `isintance` function is also called to check for list object, which returns true.

Why this happens is there a way proper way to check if the object is a list, and why data and data1 are not equal even if they seem like identical?

Comment: can you please post the code with line numbers?

Comment: What do you get when you write `print type(data)`? This will surely give you the answer

Comment: You do it as you show: `isinstance(thing, list)`. Better yet, in general, you *don't* check it, as if you had e.g. a tuple that would still be fine; see *"duck typing"*. Beyond that, please cut down to a [mcve].

Comment: `json.dumps` produces a Python string that *encodes* a list, not a Python list.

Answer (score 1):

The result of calling [`json.dumps()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps) is a JSON formatted string, so after executing the line:

```
data=json.dumps(wappalyzer['apps'][list_of_apps[0]]['script']) #[u'checkout\\.google\\.com', u'wallet\\.google\\.com']
```

`data` is a string. That's why the `isinstance(data, list)` returns `False`.